# Image based ML paradigms where input vector integrates pixel intensity with pixel coordinates

Tags: convolutional-neural-network, image-classification, computer-vision, spatial-transformer

Are there image based machine learning formulations where the input is not just the plain 2D image grid but one where pixel intensity $I(x,y)$, at position $(x,y)$ is coupled with the actual position information $(x,y)$. This is so that the final input vector to the machine learning problem may be a set of triplets $(I(x,y),x,y)$. This is applicable to situations where the sensor grid is irregular and not necessarily rectangular for example.

A paper that gets close is this
"Dynamic Graph CNN for Learning on Point Clouds"
https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07829

But I am hoping there is work on irregular 2D sensor/image grids. Any references to papers would be greatly appreciated.